# booting an iBook from a live linux usb drive

Tags: usb, startup, books

I have a live usb image that seems to run on my lenovo thinkpad that I'd like to get to work on an old iBook (Model A1007). Things I have tried so far

1) Just turning the computer on with the usb in the usb drive.
2) Holding the option key while restarting the computer
3) Following these instructuions:
http://ben-collins.blogspot.com/2010/08/booting-your-ibook-g4-from-usb-stick.html

but replaced all instances of "txbi" to "yaboot"

First

In this case I booted while holding down `Cmd + Option + O + F`
and typed:

```
 boot ud:,\\yaboot
```

This brings up a circle with a line through it icon.
Maybe this means it failed to boot from the usb device so I tried the alternative walk though after a restart and the same key combenation:

```
 > dev usb0
```

which returned

> `dev usb0 ok`

then

```
 > ls
```

returned

> ```
> ff9a6d98: /disk@1
> ok
> ```

then

```
 > dev disk@1
```

returned

> ```
> > dev disk@1 ok
> ```

then

```
 pwd
```

returned

> ```
> pwd /pci@f2000000/usb@18 ok
> ```

then

```
 boot /pci@f2000000/usb@18/disk@1:,\\yaboot
```

returned

> ```
> boot /pci@f2000000/usb@18/disk@1:,\\yaboot can't open :/pci@f2000000/usb@18/disk@1:,\\yaboot
> ```

Does this suggest a problem with my usb drive? Or perhaps I am doing something wrong with this attempted way of booting from a usb. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search for Lenovo ThinkPad shows these machines use Intel processors. I believe your iBook uses a PowerPC processor. So one would expect the USB flash drive to fail to work with your iBook, if you can boot using the ThinkPad.

### Appendix

[Ubuntu PowerPC FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ)

[Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04/release/)

[Ubuntu MATE 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.04/release/)

> Note: iBook (Model A1007) shipped with 256 MB of RAM. This is expandable to a maximum of 640 MB.

Comment: Does this mean that this would likely have worked if I used a PowerPC version of Ubuntu?

Comment: That would make a nice new question. However, I did find this link: [Which Macs are compatible with Ubuntu?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Which_Macs_are_compatible_with_Ubuntu.3F) I also added, to my answer, some links of possible Power PC downloads. Lubuntu might make a better choice than Ubuntu. It really depends on how much RAM is installed in your iBook.